# Way to handle the objects in C++

Tags: c++, filesystems

Every time when I run the code Compiler give the error of object already define and I don't know where I am making mistakes in the whole code.

Even if I do this all in one file it is working but I don't know why its not working in this style can anyone help me that where I am doing mistake in this code.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you

**student.h**

```
ifndef STUDENT
define STUDENT

class Student
{

public:
    char student_no[10];
    char student_name[20];
    char student_address[20];
    char student_score[20];
    Student();

};

Student::Student()
{//constructor
    student_no[0] = 0; student_name[0] = 0; student_address[0] = 0;
    student_score[0] = 0;
}

#endif
```

**student.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
#include "writestr.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>



int main(){
    char filename[20];
    Student s;
    cout << "Enter the file name:" << flush;
    cin.getline(filename, 19);
    ofstream stream(filename, ios::out);
    if (stream.fail()) {
        cout << "File open failed!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    while (1) {
        cin >> s; // read fields of person
        if (strlen(s.student_name) == 0) break;
        // write person to output stream
        stream << s; // write fields of person
    }
    return 1;
}
```

[Problems occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Fip.png)

This is the portion where I write the streaming code.

**writestr.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
#include "readper.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

ostream & operator << (ostream & stream, Student & s)
{ // insert fields into file
    stream << s.student_name << s.student_no << s.student_address
        << s.student_score;
    return stream;
}
```

**readper.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
#include "student.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>   
istream & operator >> (istream & stream, Student & s)
{ // read fields from input
    cout << "Enter Student Name, or <cr> to end: " << flush;
    stream.getline(s.student_name, 30);

    if (strlen(s.student_name) == 0) return stream;
    cout << "Enter Student Name: " << flush; stream.getline(s.student_name, 30);
    cout << "Enter Student Id Number: " << flush; stream.getline(s.student_no, 30);
    cout << "Enter Address: " << flush; stream.getline(s.student_address, 30);
    cout << "Enter Score: " << flush; stream.getline(s.student_score, 15);

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: When asking question about build errors, first of all create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Then copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* build log from the shown example. And also include comments on the line in the code where the errors are. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: By the way, your overloaded "input" operator `>>` should not output anything. What happens if you try to use it with a file or string stream instead of `std::cin`? Then the user of your program shouldn't input anything and the output is all wrong.

Comment: Never include 'cpp' files

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? If you are using the latest one you can directly initialize class members at the time of declaration in `Student` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **defining** (not just declaring) the constructor in the header file:

```
Student::Student()
{//constructor
    student_no[0] = 0; student_name[0] = 0; student_address[0] = 0;
    student_score[0] = 0;
}
```

This defines the constructor (generates the code) again and again in every cpp that includes the header file. Since this definition has no `inline` keyword, it may exist exactly once in the program, not multiple times. Defining the non-inline constructor in multiple translation units  (cpp files) causes the error.

Possible solutions:

1. Move the constructor definition into the class, or
2. Prefix it by an `inline` keyword, or
3. Move it to one of the cpp files

Another issue: you include cpp files, which cause a lot more issues by declaring the same thing again and again. Simply add them to the project/makefile/etc, instead of including:

```
#include "writestr.cpp"
```